Cross-Site cookies is not working in netlify deployment
When a successful login occurs from the backend, I'm trying to set a cookie, but it's coming up as 'undefined' on Netlify, while everything works fine on localhost. When I check the Cookies from the application tab in the browser's inspect tool, the cookie is visible, but when I try to retrieve it using Cookies.get() from js-cookie, it returns 'undefined'. CORS origin is set to the site's link in the backend with 'credential true'.
Netlify live link: https://workmanager-srijonashraf.netlify.app/
//Backend Controller
exports.UserLogin = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let reqBody = req.body;
    let result = await EmployeeModel.find(reqBody).count();
    if (result === 1) {
      // Create JWT Token
      const token = CreateJWTToken(reqBody);

      res.cookie("token", token, {
        httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
        secure: true, 
        sameSite: "None", 
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      });

      res
        .status(200)
        .json({ status: "success", email: reqBody["email"], token: token });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({ status: "fail", data: "No User Found" });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(200).json({ status: "error", data: e });
  }
};

//CORS

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [
      "http://localhost:5173",
      "https://workmanager-srijonashraf.netlify.app",
      "https://work-manager-frontend.vercel.app",
      "https://work-manager-frontend.vercel.app/:1",
      /\.netlify\.app$/,
      /\.vercel\.app$/,
    ],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

//Axios Call From Frontend

function UserLogin(email, password) {
  const URL = `${BASE_URL}/UserLogin`;
  const postBody = { email, password };

  return axios
    .post(URL, postBody, { withCredentials: true })
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.data.status === "success") {
        setUserEmail(email);
        console.log("All Cookies", Cookies.get());
        console.log("Token from cookies:", Cookies.get('token'));
        return true;
      } else {
        console.log("Login Failed");
        return false;
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      return false;
    });
}


Cookies.get() response from console of deployed site
I have tried:

Changing the CORS policies
Set the origin to wildcard (*)
Deployed with and without credential : true properties in CORS

